# Connect SSH to server on port 2222 via the terminal

Tags: ssh, terminal, webserver

I cannot SSH into my server via the terminal. So far I've tried:

`ssh root@ip-address` and `ssh username@ip-address`

but neither has worked. I'm getting a blank screen for a while and then eventually

> operation timed out

I've also tried switching to a different location with a different Internet Service Provider, so I'm fairly sure that the problem isn't a firewall.

I can login via FTP.

This is what I get:

```
$ ssh hosting-account-username@ip-address
ssh: connect to host ip-address port 22: Operation timed out
```

I've also tried this with no result:

```
$ nc ip-address 22
```

I've pinged the address:

```
$ ping ip-address
64 bytes from ip-address icmp_seq=143 ttl=45 time=44.543 ms
64 bytes from ip-address icmp_seq=143 ttl=45 time=43.686 ms
64 bytes from ip-address icmp_seq=143 ttl=45 time=46.501 ms
-- and so on
```

My hosting company has told me I do have SSH, but on port 2222 (instead of 22) because I have a shared hosting account and tried this:

```
$ nc ip-address -p [2222]
nc: missing hostname and port
usage: nc [-46AacCDdEFhklMnOortUuvz] [-K tc] [-b boundif] [-i interval]
          [-p source_port] [--apple-delegate-pid pid] [--apple-delegate-uuid uuid]
          [-s source_ip_address] [-w timeout] [-X proxy_version]
          [-x proxy_address[:port]] [hostname] [port[s]]

$ ssh username@ip-address:2222
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-address:2222: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Not sure what else to try.

Comment: The problem is most likely one of - routing issue (does ping work?) or a firewall issue or the SSH server us not rubbing or us not listening on the correct interface.

Comment: @JimDanner in fact, the connection DOES NOT work. We know this because the operation times out rather then being closed.

Comment: @davidgo Well, the IP connection works (there’s a response to the ping), but obviously the ssh connection doesn’t. I agree there can still be multiple causes.

Comment: @Chameleon With FTP, you could download `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and see if there are lines that *don’t* start with a `#` that reveal anything interesting.

Comment: I've cropped the whitespace from the screenshots, but in the future you can just copy & paste plain text from a terminal (use the Code / CTRL-K formatting). Also, I'm not sure about your `ssh`, but mine has the `-p [port]` option, so adding `-p 2222` might solve your problem. Or `ssh user@address:port`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-p` option in `nc` command is for source port and you need to specify destination port.

Try `$ nc ip-address 2222` to check if you can reach the port.

Also I don't think than `ssh` command accept the syntax `hostname:port`.

Try `$ ssh -p 2222 username@ip-address` instead.

Comment: scp -p 2222 localfile user@host:/file/path and ssh -p 2222 user@host remotecommand

Comment: @SampoSarrala With `scp`, the port option uses capital P: `scp -P 2222 user@host...`

Answer (score 3):

It is rather common to run the `ssh` service on a non-default port to prevent brute force attacks, etc. so you need to specify the (correct!) port number.  If you aren't sure what this is, you can check with your service provider or if you have some other method of accessing the service with `sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ssh`

To connect, assuming you are using port 2222

```
ssh -p 2222 user@host
```

Will work.  For `scp` or `sftp`, the option changes to upper case so

```
scp -P 2222 user@host:/path/to/remote/file /path/to/local/destination
```

If you are on a *nix system (Mac included) you can edit `~/.ssh/config` and create profiles that handle the various port options, etc.

```
Host webhost
    HostName www.example.com
    Port 2222
    User webmaster
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/www-private-key
```

And then simply connect via `ssh webhost` since the `webhost` profile specifies hostname, port number, user, etc. for the connection.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to use `ssh user@IP -p 2222`. Was asked for the password, got  in right away.

Comment: This is what [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1388316/432690) advised few hours ago. If this works for you, you should accept the other answer instead of writing your own that only duplicates the solution. Please take our short [tour] to learn Super User is not a forum. I think your answer should be deleted, unless you have something new to add (if so, [edit] the answer).

Comment: I have accepted the answer - but I would like to point out that you can also type `-p 2222` after `user@IP` instead of before it. So `ssh user@IP -p 2222` and `ssh -p 2222 user@IP` will both work.